# I need from php to open and get data from file, but

Tags: php

this file is accounting program data file, where is stored data about costumers,goods and so...  It's name is **0.skl  1.skl 0.rea 1.rea**.

When I open them with php and get data, its like encrypted, some words are obvious, but there are too many unknown symbols

How can I decrypt it? I need to use that information with **mysql**, I must get data with **php** and send it to **mysql**.

Comment: You should consult with the documentation accompanying the program that generated those files. The data can be in any form, compressed, encrypted... Unless you understand the file's structure, you will have a hard time digging out the data from it.

Answer (score 2):

rI think you will find that you have opened a binary file, which has been created in a format specific to your accounting application. I would guess it is not designed to be opened by anything else.

I use Sage accounting, there are functions in this to export your data into text files such as CVS and the like (or XML. or even Excel formats). I would guess your system can do that too.

Then you can use PHP/MySQL to parse/import the data.